# The page at "domain" says: It is not possible geolocate your position

Tags: javascript, android

I've implemented some features that requires geolocation of the user in my website, but whenever the user reaches the page that requires geolocation, a popup message that says "The page at "domain" says: It is not possible geolocate your position." come up

these are my files

MainActivity.java

```
package com.ibrahimalesayi.sawaleen;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


        public class GeoWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
            @Override
            public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin,
                                                           GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
                // Always grant permission since the app itself requires location
                // permission and the user has therefore already granted it
                callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
            }
        }
        WebView webView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            webView.loadUrl("domain");
            WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
            webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            webView.setWebChromeClient(new GeoWebChromeClient());
        }

        private class MywebClient extends WebViewClient {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if (webView.isFocused() && webView.canGoBack()) {
                webView.goBack();
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }

        }
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="schemas.android/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="schemas.android/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@drawable/logos"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/logor"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sawaleen"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="schemas.android/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="schemas.android/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

what is wrong with my app?